# 19.10: GNOME fractional scaling, fullscreen video goes bogus

Tags: gnome, video, 19.10, fullscreen, 20.04

I do have a Toshiba z20t-c with Ubuntu 19.10, 20.04 and Kubuntu 20.04 on it (also tried different daily-live-isos).

In GNOME, when I'm at another than 100% scaling and putting a video into fullscreen mode (e.g. via Firefox or gnome videos) it starts switching between different scaling/cropping/zoom levels every half second...

This doesn't happen, when there is another window in the foreground (an "always-on-top" terminal, e.g.)!

Also, KDE doesn't have this problem.

Any idea, where and how I could report and/or debug this? I'm not entirely sure, but I think it has been working some time in the past...

Thanks in advance,
pheidrias

Comment: 20.04 anything is pre-release, so instead of reporting it here, http://launchpad.net is the place to go. If it happens in 19.10, here's the place. And, TY for letting us know the issue is GNOME-specific (i.e., works AOK w/ KDE).

Comment: Hi K7AAY,

thanks for your answer.

In fact, the problem exists in ubuntu 19.10, too. 

When reporting in launchpad - which package shall I report it against?

Thanks,
pheidrias

Comment: It exists in 19.10,, so it belongs here, too; report against 20.04 and note what you found

Comment: Okay...I've investigated somewhat more systematically. 

It looks like the system is leaving the e.g. 150% scaling when switching to fullscreen. It seems to so scale everything (the GNOME-activity bar on the right, e.g.) down to 100% and back and forth...

Systematic approach: Fresh install and upgrade of 19.10, login, start firefox, open youtube and start a video, go fullscreen - everything is fine (atm - I had problems with firefox and fullscreen before).
Then, starting some video with the GNOME-Video-app (or vlc) gives the fullscreen trouble.

How can I dig further into this?
Tx!

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue on popos 19.10 , it is bug in xrandr fractional scaling , on ubuntu 19.10 fractional scaling is not enabled , so if you set to 200% scale , it will work for you.
Dirty trick is to remove everything .gnome .config in your dir and reboot